# Nextauth TypeError: Cannot read property 'useState' of null when using SessionProvider

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

When I try to add in SessionProvider to my NextJS app, I get
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'useState' of null` error.
I can't understand what I'm supposed to do?
I am able to sign in using Google without any problems. It was only when I added in the SessionProvider provider that I got this error.

// _app.tsx

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

// [...nextauth.js]

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
      signIn: "/auth/signin",

  }
})
```

I also noticed that my session was an empty object when logging it out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me before. You can try putting "next-auth": "^4.0.1" to your "dependencies" in package.json.

Comment: How did you figure out the answer?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the way I solved this issue is by doing two things:

1. I added the following line of code in my "dependencies" in the package.json file

   `"next-auth": "^4.22.1"`
2. I updated both npm and node with the following lines of code:

   `npm update npm update npm -g`

And then when I restarted my server everything worked perfectly.